# Regex: match sub-string between keywords including the keywords

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have the following string:

```
account management: | success, failure| default do
```

I want to match "success, failure". I can do that with the following expression:

```
(?<=[|])(.*)(?=[|])
```

However, there are cases where the pipe ("|") is missing. I tried the following to capture "success, failure":

```
(?<=success)(.*)(?=failure)
```

But that matches only the comma in the middle. Is there some way I can match a sub-string between 2 keywords and the match to include those keywords (I am working with python 3.x)? Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with `success.*?failure`?

Comment: Use `r'\|([^|]+)'`

Comment: @revo thank you for the solution. It works as expected!